# Fontspec with bibtex with accents give me a bug : "Missing \endcsname inserted. \char"

Tags: biblatex, fontspec, babel, accents, scrbook

i try to get out of a 3 days trouble, hope for your help !

I just want to find my bibliography in my font without bug...

I'm using `\documentclass{scrbook}`, & `{Adobe Garamond Pro}` font with `\fontspec` for writing my thesis, but I have a problem with my bibtex bibliography : two ways.

1. when I compile xelatex-biblatex-xelatex, `\printbibliography` is done, it's printed in a font I don't know (may be a original font of Latex),
2. and after if I try to force my `{Adobe Garamond Pro}` font with `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontspec{Adobe Garamond Pro}}`
3. or with `\newfontfamily\normalfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}`,

when I compile xelatex-biblatex-xelatex, come a lot of `"Missing \endcsname inserted. \char"`

Of course, I use accents in my Biblio.bib because my literacy is in french & I work with the Papers2 bibliography application…

I don't know if I have to search in any direction :

- why `\bibfont` `\natbib`or `\bibtex` didn't accept accents ?
- may `\frenchb`of `\babel` have a solution with a `\frenchbsetup`? I don't think
- or in `\fontenc` or `\fontspec`directions

Please help.
Thanks

That's my config :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\vfamily}
    \addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\vfamily}      
    \addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\vfamily\small}  
    \addtokomafont{footnote}{\vfamily}              
\usepackage{fontspec}                           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        
\usepackage{xltxtra}                            
    \newfontfamily\vfamily{Adobe Garamond Pro}
%   \newfontfamily\normalfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} % or point 3
\usepackage{xunicode}                           
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}             
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}          
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}             
    \frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}    
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
    \MakeOuterQuote{"}                          
    \frenchspacing                                  
    \usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authortitle-icomp,doi=false]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
    \AtBeginBibliography{\def\UrlFont{\\\scriptsize}}                       
%\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont}  % point 2    

\begin{document}
\fontspec{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\lipsum[1]\footcite[13]{Deotte:1993ve}\lipsum[2]\footcite[13]{Ricoeur:2000ga}
\printbibliography % point 1
\end{document}
```

And my Biblio.bib

```
@article{Ricoeur:2000ga,
author = {Ric{\oe}ur, Paul}, % I know that the problem is here :s
title = {{L'{\'e}criture de l'histoire et la repr{\'e}sentation du pass{\'e}}},
journal = {ahess},
year = {2000},
volume = {55},
number = {4},
pages = {731--747},
doi = {10.3406/ahess.2000.279877},
rating = {0},
date-added = {2014-01-29T09:45:37GMT},
date-modified = {2014-01-29T09:46:30GMT},
url = {http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/ahess_0395-       2649_2000_num_55_4_279877},
uri = {\url{papers2://publication/doi/10.3406/ahess.2000.279877}}
}

@book{Deotte:1993ve,
author = {D{\'e}otte, Jean-Louis},
title = {{Le mus{\'e}e, l'origine de l'esth{\'e}tique}},
publisher = {L'Harmattan},
year = {1993},
address = {Paris},
language = {fran{\c c}ais},
rating = {0},
date-added = {2013-07-08T22:13:04GMT},
date-modified = {2014-01-29T10:03:20GMT},
uri = {\url{papers2://publication/uuid/4A77F971-C505-4B1A-AB84-6647B00EAAF0}}
}
```

Comment: When using Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX you should use utf as inputencoding (tough not loading package `inputenc`) and drop the loading of package `fontenc` as `fontspec` does the right thing for you.

Comment: Is your .bib file utf8-encoded? Do you use bibtex or biber? On advantage of biber, among many others, is that it understands utf8.

Comment: BTW: Not everyone has commercial fonts like Adobe Garamond, but testing your example with TeX Gyre Heros or Pagella works just fine. (all files utf8-encoded and using biber)

Comment: Added: utf8 is the recommended way these days: it will be read on any system without a problem. Also, delete  any mention of inputenc & xunicode since you compile with xelatex, and fontenc since you use an opentype font. Why do you load lmodern ?

Comment: thank @Bernard & @Johannes_B for your help. I used `bibtex` but I'm migrating to `biber`according yours advices. For answer yours questions : - I don't know my .bib encoding, but now I try `[bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}` to attempt respond to your recommendations ;). I don't know why I use `lmodern`, is it outdated ? I suppose.

Comment: @Zouib : usually a .bib file as used by bibtex is an ascii file (check if there are accented letters in it). JabRef can check the encoding (Menu File–>Database properties) and you can choose the default encoding Menu Preferences–>General). This way you can convert the encoding (however save a copy of the original file, just in case…)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing XeLaTeX. Your files *must* be saved as UTF-8 (well, it's possible to have other encodings, but it's definitely not recommended).

The `inputenc` package mustn't be loaded; `fontenc` may, but in your case it's completely useless. Don't load `lmodern`, which is not tailored for XeLaTeX. Also `textcomp` is generally useless with XeLaTeX. Finally, `xunicode` shouldn't be called for (but it's not a problem, because it's already loaded by `fontspec`). Use `xltxtra` only if you need its features.

Moreover, the main font should be declared with `\setmainfont`. Defining `\normalfont` as a font family is wrong. After using `\setmainfont` you can use `\normalfont` for returning to a "clean state", as I did in the `\addtokomafont. You can use`\rmfamily`, instead, if you just don't want the default sans serif font that's used by default in section titles, but you want to keep boldface.

Avoid direct calls of `\fontspec`.

Here's a polished version of your document. The `filecontents*` environment and `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` are just for making the example selfcontained. Use `\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}` in your document. Finally, since I don't have the font you want, I changed it, but you find the good call commented out.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Ricoeur:2000ga,
author = {Ric{\oe}ur, Paul}, % I know that the problem is here :s
title = {{L'{\'e}criture de l'histoire et la repr{\'e}sentation du pass{\'e}}},
journal = {ahess},
year = {2000},
volume = {55},
number = {4},
pages = {731--747},
doi = {10.3406/ahess.2000.279877},
rating = {0},
date-added = {2014-01-29T09:45:37GMT},
date-modified = {2014-01-29T09:46:30GMT},
url = {http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/ahess_0395-2649_2000_num_55_4_279877},
uri = {\url{papers2://publication/doi/10.3406/ahess.2000.279877}}
}

@book{Deotte:1993ve,
author = {D{\'e}otte, Jean-Louis},
title = {{Le mus{\'e}e, l'origine de l'esth{\'e}tique}},
publisher = {L'Harmattan},
year = {1993},
address = {Paris},
language = {fran{\c c}ais},
rating = {0},
date-added = {2013-07-08T22:13:04GMT},
date-modified = {2014-01-29T10:03:20GMT},
uri = {\url{papers2://publication/uuid/4A77F971-C505-4B1A-AB84-6647B00EAAF0}}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authortitle-icomp,doi=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{lipsum}                         

\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
%\frenchspacing % already done by French

%\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro} % I don't have it
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\small}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\normalfont}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\def\UrlFont{\\\scriptsize}}                       

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footcite[13]{Deotte:1993ve}\lipsum[2]\footcite[13]{Ricoeur:2000ga}

\printbibliography % point 1

\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of the bibliography that I got after running Biber.

[image]

---

With TeXShop it's easy to change the encoding of a file: *don't touch* the general preferences, but simply add at the beginning of the file the line

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

Close and reopen the file. It should work correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg. I cleaned my code according to your advices, but the problem persists (`missing endcsname inserted... \char`). I'm installing biber and the new version of biblatex (& At the same time I discovered Tex Live Utility that I update) & after, it should run… 

After your cleaning, I returned to `[applemac]{inputenc}` for accents in my text & title…

I try with biber & I tell you how it happened.

Comment: Ok, I try with biber & biblatex updated, it's perfect without `applemac{inputenc}`: no error message, all right. But, in my really text (how isn't really `lipsum`) my french accents aren't recognized... What package could replace my old friend `applemac{imputenc}` ?

Comment: @Zouib You must choose UTF-8 as encoding for your document. What editor are you using?

Comment: Dear @egreg in my preferences->general TexShop, I used the encodage `Latin 1`. I change this morning to UTF-8… but I imagine that in preferences->composition I have to change something (because it don't change anything when I compose). Sorry, I'm so newbie…

Comment: @Zouib I'll add to my answer how you can do.

Comment: incredible, everything work perfectly !!!!! Thank you very much

Comment: One more question : why my line `@book{GoncalvesdaCosta:2000tw,
author = {Goncalves Da Costa, H{\'e}lo{\"\i}sa}`… don't compile right with the ï ? I tested all accents, ï `{\"\i}` & î `{\^\i}` are the only encodage defaults in all my bibliography… (sorry if it's not the place of this question)

Comment: @Zouib Maybe you can open a new question

Comment: Hi @egreg - DG' resolves the second question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158550/i-i-font-encoding/158572?noredirect=1#comment365312_158572) It may adds interest about our discussion here. Thanks