# biblatex and special character \'{\i}

Tags: biblatex, accents, input-encodings

I want to cite an article from a spanish author having the character í in his name. MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib1.bib}
@article{test,
author = {Garc{\'{\i}}a, S.},
journal = {J. Phys.},
number = {7},
pages = {535},
title = {Some interesting title},
volume = {13},
year = {1987}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=phys,
    articletitle=false,
    backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{test}.

Test: Garc{\'{\i}}a.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This produces an error: `./main.tex:31: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ÃÅ (U+301) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.`, although in the normal text the name appears correct. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864) and the questions linked to there.