# Accents in Biber problem with "í"

Tags: biber

I read the posts about adding accents in Biber this way:

```
\{'a}
```

but this is not working with the letter i. What can I do?

Comment: Just input it directly should help.

Comment: I get this : Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)

Comment: Can you make a small compilable example for us?  I am not sure if `biber` is causing this or your input is strange. Starting point: Placing an accent on an i will never give you an `í`.

Comment: Are you sure the input is saved as utf8?

Comment: It should be `{\'a}`, not `\{'a}` and similarly for `i`: `{\'i}`

Comment: Yes.. my fault!

Comment: @Johannes_B `\'i`, `\^i`, `\"i` and ``\`i`` have been working for several years.

Comment: See also [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is `{\'a}` and `{\'i}`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gh,
  author = {Gonzalo Higua{\'i}n},
  title = {How to score goals},
  journal = {Naples Journal of Soccer},
  year = 2016,
}
@article{mc,
  author = {M{\'a}rtin C{\'a}ceres},
  title = {How not to be scored goals},
  journal = {Hurr{\`a} Juventus},
  year = 2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{gh} and \cite{mc}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, direct input is possible by using UTF-8:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{gh,
  author = {Gonzalo Higuaín},
  title = {How to score goals},
  journal = {Naples Journal of Soccer},
  year = 2016,
}
@article{mc,
  author = {Mártin Cáceres},
  title = {How not to be scored goals},
  journal = {Hurrà Juventus},
  year = 2016,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{gh} and \cite{mc}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the  ``{\'i}`` syntax specific to bibliographies? I was familiar with ``\'\i``, but it appears that the dotless i ``\i`` doesn't work here, even when wrapped in curly brackets.