# How to fix weird `\'i` behavior when using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, characters, overleaf

I started to use `biblatex` not so long ago. Everything is working properly in general, however, I have had some trouble with the special character `\'i`, used in order to obtain the character "í".

It will render only under very specific conditions. For example, I have had no trouble when render it using the `book` entry type, but with the `misc` entry type there is almost every time a problem and here is where the specific conditions begin. Let's see the **MWE first**.

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{Citation}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### references.bib

```
@misc{Citation,
    title={{\'a}{\'i}}
}
```

As you can see this MWE causes an error, a curious thing discovered is that if you make a brief modification in the **references.bib** file, the error is gone: instead of `{\'a}{\'i}` put `{\'i}{\'a}`.

A brief look at the **output.bbl** file can tell what is happening in the background: the input `\'i` is being interpreted as `\'\i{}`. This happens both in the `misc` and `book` entry types, the difference is that, for some reason, if the **reference.bib** (without the previous modification) is modified changing the entry type from `misc` to `book`, it will render without problem.

## Question

How can this be fixed? What should be the correct workaround?

## Additional info

I am working in an online platform (namely Overleaf).

Comment: Please see [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864) and related and linked questions.

Comment: Seems as though `\MakeSentenceCase` has some problems with the characters ... (`biblatex-ieee` uses `\MakeSentenceCase` for `@misc`s, but not for `@book`s). But maybe Biber's output routine needs tweaking.

Comment: Do you know which version of biber Overleaf is using?

Comment: @moewe Your comment reminds me another test I performed. The referencing style I have is IEEE, as you can see. The first character in the title is set to uppercase, and the rest of them are set to lowercase. Probably you noticed that when the `\'i` is at the beginning no uppercase alteration is performed. One more thing is that if you delete the `\'a` (leaving the `\'i` alone), the problem disappears but no character is rendered.

Comment: @PLK To be honest I have no idea, I guess I could ask them, however I also tried it with ShareLaTeX, obtaining the same result (same error).

Comment: @Hans: You could look in the blg and the log-file there the versions are recorded. Beside this imho the best solution is to avoid commands in the bib-file and to enter í directly (along with a suitable inputenc).

Comment: @PLK The current version of biber on Overleaf is 2.1.

Comment: @Hans: since `biber` understands `utf8`, why don't you simply type `í` or `à` durectly from your keyboard? In short: encode your .bib file in UTF8.

Comment: @PLK I can reproduce the behaviour with current Biber 2.4. I guess that `\MakeSentenceCase` has some trouble with the characters from the `.bbl` (`\'{a}\'\i{}`).

Comment: @moewe - hmm - if you think we have a bug here, can you file it?

Comment: @PLK Not sure if it is a bug. I will file a report and you can see what to do with it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You mentioned that you're working on Overleaf, so here's what you can do to get your Overleaf project to compile correctly.)

### Method 1: Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

...which are able to handle UTF8 characters out of the box.

On Overleaf, you can set the engine to use by clicking on the Settings icon (the gear icon on the upper right of the editor, just next to your user name), and then selecting XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX from the "LaTeX engine" drop list. Don't forget to click on "Save Project Settings".

### Method 2: Tweak biber

If you need to use pdfLaTeX, you can tweak biber to use the `--output-safechars` option, as outlined in [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864).

On Overleaf, you can do this by adding a `latexmkrc` file to your project, and then put the following line in it:

```
$biber = "biber --output-safechars %O %S";
```