# how to solve a Unicode char' (U+301) error?

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I have a problem within ShareLaTex. I copied a reference from biblatex and pasted it into my bib file and the ignored command is

```
author={Ran{\v{n}}ik, Jk{\v{r}}{\n}́}
```

which should generate

[image: not this: {Ran{\v{n}}ik, Jk{\v{r}}{\n}́}]

I get the following error message:

```
Unicode char' (U+301)
```

I add references to my bib file with `~` signs or accents.

Comment: U+0301 is a combining accent, it is best to enter accented commands as single characters or as tex markup `\'{e}` rather than e followed by a unicode combining acute

Comment: I copy reference from bibatex and paste it in my bib file and the command is ignored     
                  author={Ran{\v{n}}ik, Jk{\v{r}}{\n}́

Comment: ah biblatex/biber not bibtex, you didn't say... still it's hard to debug without an example. (or even the complete error message)

Comment: Is the `'` after the last bracket there on purpose? Isn't there a closing bracket missing at the end?

Comment: yes it is on purpose author={Ran{\v{n}}ik, Jk{\v{r}}{\n}́},

Comment: The `́` character is the obvious culprit. Retype the name using proper encoding. Moreover `\n` makes no sense. If I google for `Ranňik` I get nothing

Comment: Jk{\v{r}}{\i}́}

Comment: when i write it like this Mac{\'{i}} an error occurs

Comment: How can I convince biber to produce the correct unicode character for í?

Comment: It's quite obvious that you should at least use `i` if you want an accented `i`. But if you're using `biblatex`, why not simply `Ranňik Jkrí`?

Comment: Also relevant: [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864) as well as linked questions.

Answer (score 9):

Just type in the name using UTF-8 characters:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author={Ranňik, Jkří},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2016},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Only this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

`\n` is generally not defined and the `'` afterwards generates the error message. About the "`{\'{i}} an error occurs`" from your comments: That should be `\'{\i}`, where `\i` creates an "i" without dot, so that the "´" can be placed there.

Thus `author={Ran{\v{n}}ik, Kj{\v{r}}{\'{\i}}}` should produce the right output.

About accents etc. you can find additional information at:

[How to type special/accented letters in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8857/6865)

["accents" tag wiki](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/accents/info)

[Escaped codes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes)

Comment: For being BibTeX compatible it should be `Ran{\v{n}}ik, Kj{\v{r}}{\'{i}}`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, +1, fixed my answer for the missing brackets, but `\i` instead `i` also for BibTeX, or not?