# Biber + classicthesis: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301): How to find symbol

Tags: biber, unicode, classicthesis

My problem develops as following.

1. I delete the .bbl .bcf .blg files.
2. I run pdflatex without errors.
3. I run biber without errors.
4. I run pdflatex again, and I get the error

   "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)
   (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX
   │l.15 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

As I use classicthesis, my configuration for biber looks as following:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8}{biblatex} 
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

How can that problem arise?

edit: Like the comments' links to other problems outlined, biber--output-safechars worked for me.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329239/how-to-solve-a-unicode-char-u301-error

Comment: I looked into this and followed each step, but it does not work for me.

Comment: The problem is usually a `\'{\i}` or `\'i` or something similar. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864 and linked questions. Or try `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{XXXXX}` and search for `XXXXX`

Comment: @varantir Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that includes the problematic .bib entry?

Comment: Though I must say that I think `--output-safechars` is the "least best" of all options. Using Unicode characters like `í` directly instead of `\'{\i}` or at least `\'i` or [PLK's sourcemap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251381/35864) seem nicer to me.

Comment: What font encoding are you using?