# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)(inputenc)

Tags: bibtex, errors, unicode, input-encodings

I get this error message, during compiling my .tex-document.

```
line 234 - ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \cleardoublepage
```

I am writing my thesis right now and I am very confused about this error message, since it seems to be connected to a special character, which I do not use in my manuscript. The solution up to now was the reloading of an older version of my manuscript...after some hours of work and after several times of successful compiling this error suddenly occurs again. I don't get it why, since I just write some text, add some figures and nothing more...

any suggestions, how I can solve that issue? I have no idea, what kind of MWE I should post here :( where does this comment "line234" refer to. Line 234 is normal text in my manuscript...

Comment: Check out the comments on [this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329239/how-to-solve-a-unicode-char-u301-error). There might be something in there that could solve your issue. In particular using `\'e` for accented characters.

Comment: I kind of solved the problem for now by using

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'{e}}

before \begin{document}. Well, I am happy about it, but I am still not understand, what the actual problem was. Why do I have to declare some unicode and some not???

Comment: @MariusKnapp That's wrong: U+0301 is a combining character; if you have the combination `U+0065 U+0301`, your definition would produce `eé`.

Comment: Experienced this problem with ``\'{\i}`` in a ``.bib`` file compiled with ``biblatex``. Problem solved by using ``\'{i}`` instead, which is strange because the backslash in front of the ``i`` used to be recommended. Anyhow the i prints correctly that way.

Comment: We should really pick one of these questions to be the canonical question we redirect dupes to.

Comment: I had problem with `\'{i}` too. Changing in the bib file was not enough for me. I had to go in the bbl file and change there also! The bbl file had composed characters. I changed only ı́

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you copy/paste some source, it may happen that `é` had been coded as

```
U+0065 U+0301
```

which in Unicode aware environments is rendered as expected. Unfortunately `pdflatex` is *not* Unicode aware and cannot deal with combining characters, which are placed *after* the character they refer to.

The only method that gives correct results is to change the combination into the non composed character.

Doing `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'{e}}` is wrong. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\'{e}}

\begin{document}

é % non composed character U+00E9
é % composed character U+0065 U+0301
ú % composed character U+0075 U+0301

\end{document}
```

[image]

You're removing the error message, but the output is completely off.

<sub>**Note** Copying from the above will not show the precomposed characters, because either my OS or this site does normalization.</sub>

Comment: @MariusKnapp Find the offending characters and retype the correct ones.

Comment: Use xelatex to complie and works fine.

Comment: By "change the combination into the non composed character," could you write how you do that in the LaTeX code, instead of just mentioning what you should _not_ do?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Search and replace with your favorite editor.

Comment: lol. I of course meant, what do you mean by "non composed character"?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever Replace e+combining accent into `é`.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 88):

I do this:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{*************************************}
```

and look into the pdf which char produces this and delete/correct it.

Comment: Excellent method to locate the culprit! :)

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I don't understand what the asterisks represent? The entire LaTeX source code?

Comment: The line of asterisks is just here so you can easily find in the resulting pdf where is annoying unicode char... but you can use whatever char you want ;-).

Comment: This is awesome

Comment: i would give more upvotes if i could!

Comment: I just tried to upvote this only to realise I already did, many years ago!

Comment: @Tom, you stick this line of code in your preamble, compile, and then visually inspect the PDF for a line of stars. That's where the problem is. You go back to the source file and retype the offending characters. You can replace the stars by any other visually identifiable set of characters.

Comment: Very useful especially when the problem is in bibliography entries!

Comment: Fantastic solution. It just solved a prolem for me in the bibliography, where the unicode character was *not* in the source, but created by biber from `\'{\i}` instead of `\'i`

Comment: This should be an accepted answer somewhere, really useful!

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar problem:

```
Error: Unicode char ́ (U+0301)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX...;
```

It seems the problem was not in my main text but in my `.bib` file instead. I had a citation in the line in which my compilation said I had the mistake, and after checking this reference inside the `.bib` file, I found that it had several accented vowels in curly brackets. I changed the vowel in curly brackets by the corresponding "normal accented" vowel (I mean, with the vowel accented using my keyboard) and the problem went away.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I had the exact same issue and your approach worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Same issue here; your fix worked. Thank you!

Comment: Also you might need to delete all auxiliary/temporary files when dealing with error in .bib files. I had the same error, but it persisted even after deleting all non-ascii characters from .bib file. The accented vowel was still in present in .aux file, which was not recreated for some reason. I recommend deleting every file except .tex and .bib files, than recompiling. (mentioning this for anyone googling the same issue like me)

Answer (score 4):

As others have already said, the issue is the accented characters, likely in the .bib file. Replace the culprit characters there with the corresponding latex-appropriate e.g. `\'{i}`.

Answer (score 1):

Either compile in LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX, or normalize your source file to NFC form.  PDFTeX chokes on combining characters, but your accented character most likely has a canonical precomposed form that `inputenc` can handle.

You might be able to do this with `iconv -f utf8-mac -t utf8`, or [here is a little program I wrote](https://github.com/Davislor/normal-ha) that does it.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough workaround, you can use this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{\hspace{-1ex}\'{ }}

\begin{document}

chaŕ cha\'r

\Huge

chaŕ cha\'r

charŔ cha\'R

\end{document}
```

However, the workaround is indeed rather rough (look at the left R):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Compiling with XeTeX works for me, maybe because it works better with unicode.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it) a found some clarifications.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not use a link to an external page, describe in your own words what you think is the solution here. From the accepted answer changing the engine seems not to be a solution here for the OP ...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I edited my answer following your advice.