# How to insert unicode character in LaTeX document?

Tags: unicode

How to insert U+20B4 unicode character in LaTeX text? I've read that it is possible with XeTeX, but can it be done in LaTeX? Ive tried  `\char"U+20B4`, but obtained `bad character code 8372`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `DeclareUnicodeCharacter` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443042/38080). (Obviously, you need a font with that shape, or fake it somehow). Btw, the character is  ₴ https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b4/index.htm

Comment: @Rmano, thanks for reply, but `DeclareUnicodeCharacter` does not work here because there is not such char in LaTeX font.

Comment: Yes, for that I said "or fake it somehow", as brilliantly shown by @egreg's answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no font for `pdflatex` that has U+20B4 HRYVNIA SIGN ₴ (the symbol for the Ukrainian currency).

You can emulate it, with something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\hryvnia}{{%
  \fontencoding{OT1}\upshape
  \settoheight{\dimen255}{S}%
  \vphantom{S}%
  \smash{\ooalign{%
    \hfil\reflectbox{S}\hfil\cr % a reflected S
    \hfil\raisebox{0.25ex}{--}\hfil\cr % upper bar
    \hfil\raisebox{-0.05ex}{--}\hfil\cr % lower bar
  }}%
}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20B4}{\hryvnia}

\begin{document}

Ви заборгували мені ₴2000.

\end{document}
```

The definition of `\hryvnia` maybe is not the best, but the idea is this: you find out how to print the symbol and then use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` to get it when you type in the Unicode character.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well in pdf (maybe some adjusting will be done). However, it does not work for yap (internal dvi previewer), separate S and - are displayed (it seems that box transformation does not work in yap).

Comment: @Spectorsky DVI previewers generally aren't able to reproduce these effects; have you ever tried to look at a Ti*k*Z diagram on yap? Use PDF and be happy.

Comment: I use yap for preview.
To precise: yap does it correct in ps mode, but does not in pk mode (which I usually switch on). In pk mode, `\reflectbox` move box horizontally but does not reflect it. Command `\scalebox{-1}[1]` does the same as `\reflectbox`.

Comment: @Spectorsky WIthout PostScript interpretation, you cannot get reflections and other effects that DVI mode is unable to make.

Comment: yep, here is some frustration. It is interesting that yap in dvipk mode reflects 'box outline' horizontally with respect to its right side, but 'internal part' of the box is not reflected. Unfortunatelly, I cannot insert image in this comment, but you can easily reproduce it on your computer (if you have ypa installed).

Comment: @Spectorsky Sorry, but I can't see how DVI mode is helpful nowadays: there are fast and accurate PDF previewers (I'm obviously not thinking to Adobe Reader) around, for every OS. And, sorry again, I can't run `yap`, for lack of Windows, which I'm very satisfied of. ;-)