# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+0301)

Tags: errors, packages

I found a problem:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

[image]

Comment: The answers to this related question [! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)(inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443018/134144) might be helpful.

Comment: you have an " ` " in appendix that is not properly typed or escaped https://codepoints.net/U+0301 Use LuaLaTeX

Comment: @Mafsi there is no need to switch to luatex  to get an acute accent.

Comment: the acute accent will be in your bibliography you can use the answers in the duplicate question to make them show as `********` in the output then re-type them as an accented characetr or using the latex `\'` command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry, is it in my bibliography or my appendix?

Comment: you have not given much information  but looks like it is in your bibliography from what you have shown so far

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I found is one my of chapter bibliography. I presume is because I am using special character `e`

Comment: You can use é or `\'{e}`  what you can not use is a normal e followed by the Unicode combining acute U+0301

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I added `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0301}{*************************************}` and it work very well. I did not change anything in my bibliography

Comment: That is only a debugging device it will literally insert `**************` into your PDF document so that you can see where to change the bibliography (I usually use `FIX ME HERE!!!` rather than `***********`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks!!!! I am so dumb. I found is `Ben{\'\i}tez` mistake. Changed it to `Ben{'\i}tez`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Sorry, I mean I changed it to `Ben{\'i}tez`