# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ́ (U+301)

Tags: unicode

This error is related to my bibliography.
And even if I left de document of bibliography .bib blank it appears again and again.

I have checked it and I remove all the unicode character ́ (U+301), but there is no way it runs.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329239/how-to-solve-a-unicode-char-u301-error ?...

Comment: If the problematic characters come from your `.bib` file they may still be present in the auxiliary `.bbl` file even if they have been removed from the `.bib` file. Delete all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, `.toc`, ...) and recompile.

Comment: Also make sure that all your `.tex` and `.bib` files are utf8 encoded ...