# problems with accent in Latex

Tags: bibtex, accents

How can I produce the correct unicode character for `í` for a name in the bbl file as reference ?

I wrote it like this `Mac{\'{i}}as` but error still shows.

Comment: Typically one would use `\'{\i}`. However, are you processing your bibliography with any package? For example, `biber` from [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Comment: Why are you editing the bbl file by hand? You should be entering the appropriate information in the bib file.

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` with Biber [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864) as well as the linked questions there are relevant.

Answer (score -1):

I would just use `{\'i}` and this should be ok.

Comment: To whom it may concern: Why the downvote?

Comment: -1: This doesn't answer the question, really, and is not all that helpful. If someone says "X doesn't work" and it is followed by "X does work" as an answer (no further explanation), it's not helpful.

Comment: ...I'd rather suggest waiting for clarification from the OP before providing a comment-like answer like this.