# biblatex handling of \guillemotleft, \guillemotright

Tags: biblatex

I've got several .bib entries like this:

```
@article{Guinet:Torp,
  author={Louis Guinet},
  title={Les toponymes normands \guillemotleft Torp(s)\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Torpt\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Tourp(s)\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Tour(s)\guillemotright},
  journal={Annales de Normandie},
  volume=30,
  number=2,
  pages="193--197",
  year=1980,
}
```

but biblatex (or maybe biber) converts them to math mode in the .bbl file:

```
      \field{title}{{Les toponymes normands {$\guillemotleft$}Torp(s){$\guillemotright$}, {$\guillemotleft$}Torpt{$\guillemotright$}, {$\guillemotleft$}Tourp(s){$\guillemotright$}, {$\guillemotleft$}Tour(s){$\guillemotright$}}}
```

This is invalid and results in the wrong characters coming out.  How do I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{place_names}
\begin{document}
\cite{Guinet:Torp}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which gives:

LaTeX Warning: Command \guillemotleft invalid in math mode on input line 7.
LaTeX Warning: Command \guillemotright invalid in math mode on input line 7.
! Undefined control sequence.
 ...{$\guillemotright $}, \guillemotlef 
                                                  \t {T}orpt{$\guillemotrigh...

It used to work on earlier versions of TexLive (I am now using what comes with Ubuntu 16).

Comment: Can you show us a full MWE? The conversion depends on the encoding as well as `inputenc`.

Comment: I will file a bug report over at the Biber bugtracker. For the time being try and use `inputenc`, e.g. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. (Make sure your file is encoded in UTF-8.)

Comment: Thanks - which file has to be utf8?   (I've got lots of very large legacy .bib files, and I cannot change them.)

Comment: The `.tex` file should be enough, if your files are ASCII anyway that is fully compatible with UTF-8. So you can say they are UTF-8 without changing anything. If you have non-ASCII chars, more care is needed.

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/175

Comment: The use of \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} fixes my MWE, but not the real case.   I have characters like "{\=\i}" (i with macron) in my .bib file, and these give errors like: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ̄ (U+304)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem, Biber does not translate `{\=\i}` (in fact any combinations with `\i`) very well.

Comment: You may be able to fix the `\i` with a variant of PLK's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864

Comment: It looks like biber --output-safechars fixes the \=\i problem, but brings back the \guillemot problem.  So I can have one working or the other, but not both.  I will try \=i.

Comment: Yes it will, you will have to use a variant of the mapping in PLK's answer. You could search for `{\=\i}` and replace it by `ī`, then things would work out OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PLK has fixed the issue (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/175) in the development version Biber 2.8. `\guillemot`s are not converted into math mode any more.

Another possible fix is to use UTF-8 encoding where the guillemots are converted into their respective Unicode chars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Guinet:Torp,
  author={Louis Guinet},
  title={Les toponymes normands \guillemotleft Torp(s)\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Torpt\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Tourp(s)\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Tour(s)\guillemotright},
  journal={Annales de Normandie},
  volume=30,
  number=2,
  pages="193--197",
  year=1980,
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Les toponymes normands \guillemotleft Torp(s)\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Torpt\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Tourp(s)\guillemotright, \guillemotleft Tour(s)\guillemotright

\cite{Guinet:Torp}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

But we established in the comments that that causes trouble with your `ī`s, see [Input encoding error after upgrading from Biber 1.9 to Biber 2.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864).

You can fix the `ī` issue with

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=title,
            match=\regexp{\x{0131}\x{0304}},
            replace=\regexp{ī}]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These work correctly even in the mode of mathematics with even Version 2.7 (beta) of Biber:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

followed by

```
\flqq
```

instead of `\guillemotleft`

and

```
\frqq
```

instead of `\guillemotright`