# How to automate biber --output_safechars with arara?

Tags: biber, characters, font-encodings, output, arara

I'm using `arara` since my last question about [ï & î font encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158550/%C3%AF-%C3%AE-font-encoding), & before, I used the [DG'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/29873/dg) [1.1 answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158572/35024):

> **1.1 Call biber with `--output_safechars`.**
>
> To force biber to pass `{\"\i}` along unchanged, and thus getting the correct output, simply use the option `--output_safechars`:
>   `xelatex document
>   biber --output_safechars document
>   xelatex document
>   xelatex document`

When I write, I often excerpt from my bibliographic software a new file `.bib`. Do you think is it possible to integrate in `arara` the `output_safechars` like that:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber: {output_safechars: yes}% of course, it doesn't work
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
```

or in the BibTex motor line in my TexShop settings? `biber --output_safechars`

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}% it does not work either
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: @egreg I don't think `bibtex` will work here ;)

Comment: @cfr I wanted to write `biber`, of course! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% arara: biber: { options: "--output_safechars" }
```

For example, using the code from your earlier question

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{GoncalvesdaCosta:2000tw,
author = {Goncalves Da Costa, H{\'e}lo{\"\i}sa},
title = {{Les mus{\'e}es d'histoire de ville leur contribution au d{\'e}veloppement social contemporain.}},
publisher = {Universit{\'e} du Qu{\'e}bec {\`a} Montr{\'e}al},
year = {2000},
address = {Montr{\'e}al}}
\end{filecontents*}

% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: biber: { options: "--output_safechars" }
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ticomp,doi=false]{biblatex}

\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

% \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures={Common, Rare}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\normalfont}
\addtokomafont{footnotereference}{\normalfont}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\def\UrlFont{\scriptsize}}

\begin{document}
"Héloïse"\footcite{GoncalvesdaCosta:2000tw}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces the following bibliography

[image: safer bibliography]

[I compiled with `xelatex` -> `arara` -> `xelatex` just to isolate the relevant `arara` line for simplicity.]

Comment: @Zouib I think it is more Arara grammar, to be honest. You already had the Biber grammar down!