# Translate or encode biblatex language entry

Tags: biblatex, babel, languages

Since my [last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322025), I have a problem with the language field of my references, & only that (encoding, transition… I don't know). In my `.bib`, all languages field with special characters fail, for exemple "français" or "hébreu". I have all translated in english & I discovered that `babel` translates languages to french, but not all (I suppose only european languages or only latin, cyrillic or greek alphabets… I don't know). For example:

- french becomes "Français" (and disappear because it's my main language),
- dutch becomes "Néerlandais" (perfect),
- czech becomes "Tchèque".

but:

- persian stays persian. Well, I can cheat by writing "Perse" in my `.bib`,
- the same with arabic or turkish, I cheat with the french directly in `.bib`,
- armenian stays armenian, but I can't cheat, because of é of "Arménien",
- hebrew stays hebrew, I can't cheat either with "Hébreu"…

So, I can not properly reference my books in Hebrew. I would like to understand and resolve this problem. Thank you for your help.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: xelatex
% arara: biber: { options: "--output_safechars" }
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
% arara: xelatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ticomp,doi=false]{biblatex}

@book{GoncalvesdaCosta:2000tw,
author = {Goncalves Da Costa, H{\'e}lo{\"\i}sa},
title = {{Les mus{\'e}es d'histoire de ville leur contribution au d{\'e}veloppement social contemporain.}},
publisher = {universit{\'e} du Qu{\'e}bec {\`a} Montr{\'e}al},
language = {hebrew},% not translated, & Hébreu don't run…
year = {2000},
address = {Montr{\'e}al}}

\begin{document}
En fait, l'entrée \emph{language} ne supporte pas les mots à caractères spéciaux comme français ou hébreu & ils ne traduisent que quelques langues de l'anglais vers le français\footcite{GoncalvesdaCosta:2000tw}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the translation for hebrew:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets*]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ticomp,doi=false]{biblatex}
\NewBibliographyString{langhebrew}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{langhebrew={Hébreu}}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{GoncalvesdaCosta:2000tw}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's all that I needed, thank you. Why have they not thought of that in the package (babel or biblatex?), I don't know. How to suggest to them?

Comment: There are a lot of languages in the world. You can't expect french.cbx to cover them all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll study that. Another question arises: how to mark a bilingual or multilingual book? Someone knows the use ?

Comment: You could invent a language `langhebrewfrench`.

Comment: @Zouib You should be able to say `langfrench and langhebrew` (or `french and hebrew`).

Comment: @moewe: I hadn't realized that the field is a list, just tried "language=hebrew and dutch" works fine.